# How String class in initiated with constructor java

Tags: java, string

```
  public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

I dont understand how original is being converted to a char array. If i try it with a different code, its throwing a compilation error.

Comment: Every `String` has an internal `value`, and because you are in the `String` class you can view the `value` from `original`. Nothing is being converted **here**; `original` already contains a `char[]` (and a `hash`).

Comment: *"If i try it with a different code..."*: what does that mean? Can you perhaps show that code?

Comment: Ok I understand. Its throwing compliation error because its a private field in String class.

Comment: I have one more question : where is original char array is assigned when a string is created? I see only a constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` has two properties:

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];

/** Cache the hash code for the string */
private int hash; // Default to 0
```

Because you're inside the constructor of `String`, you have access right to its private field `value[]` and `hash`.

You cann't access those `private` fields from outside of String class, hence it will throw a compilation error if you attempt to do it.

Comment: thanks. Can you also tell me how the string is converted to char array?

Comment: I am not able to answer this question. I will create another one for this